# how to keep a treemap sorted after adding key-values

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have a treemap which is sorted by a `compareTo` in the `Account` class.

When I initate the treemap, it is sorted but when I try use this function (to add money to a specific account), it works only if the values I change are not the first or last in the treemap.

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static void deposit(TreeMap<Account,MyLinkedList<Customer>> map){
            boolean flag = false;
            int num ;
            int amount;
            System.out.println("please enter account number");
            num = s.nextInt();
            //for(Iterator<Account> i = map.;i.hasNext())
            for(Map.Entry<Account, MyLinkedList <Customer>> entry : map.entrySet()){
                if(entry.getKey().getAccNumber() == num){
                    flag = true;
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount");
                    amount = s.nextInt();
                    entry.getKey().setAccBalance(entry.getKey().getAccBalance()+amount);

                    Account temp = entry.getKey();
                    MyLinkedList<Customer> tempList = entry.getValue();
                    map.remove(entry.getKey());
                    map.put(temp, tempList);

                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == false) {
                System.out.println("Account doesn't exist");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to iterate over the entire Map in order to find an Account with a specific number, you defeat the purpose of using a Map.

Perhaps you should have two Maps. The additional map will be a`HashMap<Integer,Account>` and will let you locate an `Account` by account number in constant time.

This will allow you to get rid of the loop (since once you have the `Account` for the given account number, a single `map.get(account)` will get you the corresponding value. This will allow you to remove and add entries from/to the existing `TreeMap`, which you can't do while iterating over the entry set (well, you could do removal using an explicit iterator over the entry set, but not insertion).

BTW, unless your `TreeMap`'s `compareTo` uses the account balance to determine the ordering, you don't have to remove the entry from the TreeMap and re-add it with the updated balance.

Comment: first of all,thanks for the reply.i'm using the account balance to determine the ordering so i thought i have to remove and add again.and how should i implement this new map? inside the function ?

Comment: @RoyLevy Yes, you do have to remove and add again. Regarding the new Map, it wouldn't be efficient if you create it every time the method is called. You should consider passing it as a second argument to your method.

Comment: but how do i use the new hashmap to add the values ? i understand that i can get it by o(1) with get account ,but how i add the value from the hashmap(since they key is an intege) sorry im a student maybe i ask some silly questions :)

Comment: @RoyLevy Suppose you pass to your method `TreeMap<Account,MyLinkedList<Customer>> map` and `HashMap<Integer,Account> acctMap`. `Account acct = acctMap.get(num)` will give you the `Account` matching the account number `num`, assuming such account exists. Then `map.get(acct)` will give you the `MyLinkedList<Customer>` value for that account. Now you can remove the old entry, modify the key and re-add the modified entry.